# Pile of cards(Tournament of Towns)

Tags: problem-solving

I have been trying this problem for a while.But somehow, my proof(I tried an inductive approach) appears to be break down at some point.Here it is:

There is a large pile of cards.On each card one of the numbers 1,2,..,n is written.It is known that the sum of all the numbers of all the cards is equal to $kn!$ for some integer $k$.Prove that it is possible to arrange the cards into $k$ stacks so that the sum of the numbers written on the cards in each stack is equal to $n!$.(Tournament of Towns,2002)

Comment: Can you show us the steps you've taken to try and prove this statement so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to refer to the file of [Tournament of the Towns Problems and Solutions.](http://www.math.toronto.edu/oz/turgor/archives.php)  The problem is Problem 4, Fall 2002, Senior A-Level.  If you prefer not to look, the proof given *is* by induction.

There are many very nice "Russian-flavoured" problems on this site, at various levels.  A great resource!

Comment: You are welcome.  It was easy to find: I already had the site bookmarked, many nice questions.